# Should I feed my dog before exercising?

Tags: dogs, feeding, exercise

Next month, I will take my dog to take his third vaccine, so he'll be ready for walking. Nowadays, I feed him on the mornings, around 7h30 am.

Next month, I plan to go walking with him around 6h30 am. So, is it better to feed him before walking in order to give him some energy or is it recommended feed him after walking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirm with your vet (presumably the person administering the vaccine) but I would think it better to feed after exercise. If feeding prior to exercise, maybe feed in small portions or use a ridged bowl so they're not gulping down food and chewing adequately? If your dog barfs while exercising you'll definitely want to feed after instead of before. As its a puppy, I'm sure they'll have lotsa energy :)